# Search all php loads very slow?

Tags: php, mysql

My website [www.guidedsolutions.co.uk](http://www.guidedsolutions.co.uk) is build some time ago, and I don't understand a lot about php, however when I enter search crieteria i.e. Medical Sales Jobs in Scotland the search results load very fast, however when I click on search all the results page loads very very slow and sometimes doesn't even load. this is the direct link to it: [www.guidedsolutions.co.uk/medical_devices/search_results.php](http://www.guidedsolutions.co.uk/medical_devices/search_results.php) 
I am not sure which part of the php to copy so thats why I am sending the links, however if I can give any more information please do let me know.
Much appreciated.

**

```
$conds_cat = "";
$conds_loc = "";
$conds_sec = "";
$conds_sal = "";

if (isset($i["start"]) && $i["start"] > 0)
    $start = $i["start"];

if (isset($i["limit"]) && $i["limit"] > 0)
    $limit = $i["limit"];

if(isset($i["category"]) && $i["category"] != "")
    $conds_cat = "AND ".CAT_TABLE."_id ='".$i["category"]."'";

if(isset($i["location"]) && $i["location"] != "")
    $conds_loc = "AND ".LOC_TABLE."_id ='".$i["location"]."'";

$searchstring = "&category=".$i["category"]."&location=".$i["location"]."&limit=".$i["limit"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".JOB_TABLE." LEFT JOIN (".JBC_TABLE.", ".JBL_TABLE.", ".JBS_TABLE.", ".JBP_TABLE.") ON (".JBC_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id=".JOB_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id AND ".JBL_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id=".JOB_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id AND ".JBS_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id=".JOB_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id AND ".JBP_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id=".JOB_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id) WHERE ".JOB_TABLE."_display = '1' AND (".CAT_TABLE."_id IN (SELECT ".CAT_TABLE."_id FROM ".CAT_TABLE." WHERE ".CAT_TABLE."_display='1' ".$conds_cat.") AND ".LOC_TABLE."_id IN (SELECT ".LOC_TABLE."_id FROM ".LOC_TABLE." WHERE ".LOC_TABLE."_display='1' ".$conds_loc.")) GROUP BY ".JOB_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id ORDER BY ".JOB_TABLE."_rank DESC";
```

Update: Thanks dwurf,  the code that follows:

```
//echo $sql;
$res=$_Db->execute($sql);
$total = $_Db->numResults($res);

$displaylimit = $limit;

if ($total<$displaylimit+$start)
    $displaylimit=$total-$start;

$sql .= " LIMIT ".$start.", ".$limit;
//echo $sql;
$res=$_Db->execute($sql);

if($_Db->numResults($res)>0) {

    $co = 0;
    while($row=$_Db->fetchAssoc($res)) {    

        $jobs[$co]["id"]=$row[JOB_TABLE."_id"];
        $jobs[$co]["title"]=$row[JOB_TABLE."_title"];
        $jobs[$co]["product"]=getCatLocSecTitle($_Db, PDT_TABLE, $row[PDT_TABLE."_id"]);
        $jobs[$co]["salary"]=getCatLocSecTitle($_Db, SAL_TABLE, $row[SAL_TABLE."_id"]);

        $co++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This website is meant to answer specific programming questions. Your question is too vague to be answered properly. I can just confirm that the `search_results.php` takes forever to load. I would suggest that you inquire the company that built your website about your problem, or hire someone else to fix it.

Comment: Hi Carsten, Thanks for the fast reply. I understand this is vague, however I am trying to figure out a starting point so I can do the job myself. I have checked the mysql tables and all of them is about 3-4kb except one that is 80kb big, is this something I should look into, or maybe look into the php code itself? Thanks again

Comment: Since you haven't given us anything to go on, I'll make a guess: If your SQL query looks like this `.... WHERE searchfield LIKE '%searchterm%'` then that's your problem. Wildcard searching in SQL is very slow.

Comment: Given how small your tables are I suspect you are on a very poor quality shared hosting account. It would help if you can post any SQL queries you can see in your search_results.php file.

Comment: Actually I noticed that queries where both the location and category are specified execute much faster, this could mean that the php code does a fair amount of processing but the database works just fine.

Comment: @SDC if you take a look at the URL strings it seems that locations are passed to the server as IDs. I don't think LIKE is the problem here.

Comment: Hi SDC and dwurf, Thanks for the reply. I have posted some of the code above in my question. THanks again

Comment: Yes dwurf, if I specify location and category it is very fast, however if I execute a search without specifying this it loads very very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woah.

The problem is that your query is rubbish. The database design might need some work too. I see nothing wrong with the PHP (apart from excessive string manipulation) but we can only see a little bit of it there.

Lets tidy up your SQL statement so we can admire it in all its glory:

```
$sql = 
"SELECT * FROM ".JOB_TABLE." 
LEFT JOIN (
    ".JBC_TABLE.", 
    ".JBL_TABLE.", 
    ".JBS_TABLE.", 
    ".JBP_TABLE.") 
ON (
    ".JBC_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id=".JOB_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id 
    AND ".JBL_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id=".JOB_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id 
    AND ".JBS_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id=".JOB_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id 
    AND ".JBP_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id=".JOB_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id) 
WHERE 
    ".JOB_TABLE."_display = '1' 
AND (".CAT_TABLE."_id IN 
    (SELECT ".CAT_TABLE."_id FROM ".CAT_TABLE." WHERE ".CAT_TABLE."_display='1' ".$conds_cat.") 
AND ".LOC_TABLE."_id IN 
    (SELECT ".LOC_TABLE."_id FROM ".LOC_TABLE." WHERE ".LOC_TABLE."_display='1' ".$conds_loc.")) 
GROUP BY ".JOB_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id 
ORDER BY ".JOB_TABLE."_rank DESC";
```

The root of your performance problem is simple. When no category or location is set, the query retrieves a full list of *all* categories/locations for *every single job in your job table*. We say that it scales with O(m*n), which is bad.

One simple way to improve your performance is to remove that clause entirely when no location/category is set. We'll
also join to those tables directly and check that the categories should be displayed in the where clause.

```
$conds_cat = "";
$conds_loc = "";
$conds_sec = "";
$conds_sal = "";

if (isset($i["start"]) && $i["start"] > 0)
    $start = $i["start"];

if (isset($i["limit"]) && $i["limit"] > 0)
    $limit = $i["limit"];

$conds_cat = '';
$conds_loc = '';
if(isset($i["category"]) && $i["category"] != "")
    $conds_cat = " AND ".CAT_TABLE.".".CAT_TABLE."_id ='".$i["category"]."'"; 
if(isset($i["location"]) && $i["location"] != "")
    $conds_loc = " AND ".LOC_TABLE.".".LOC_TABLE."_id ='".$i["location"]."'"; 

$searchstring = "&category=".$i["category"]."&location=".$i["location"]."&limit=".$i["limit"];

$sql = 
"SELECT 
    ".JOB_TABLE.".*,
    ".JBC_TABLE.".*, 
    ".JBL_TABLE.".*, 
    ".JBS_TABLE.".*, 
    ".JBP_TABLE.".* 
FROM 
    ".CAT_TABLE.",
    ".LOC_TABLE.",
    ".JOB_TABLE."
LEFT JOIN (
    ".JBC_TABLE.", 
    ".JBL_TABLE.", 
    ".JBS_TABLE.", 
    ".JBP_TABLE.") 
ON (
    ".JBC_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id=".JOB_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id 
    AND ".JBL_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id=".JOB_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id 
    AND ".JBS_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id=".JOB_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id 
    AND ".JBP_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id=".JOB_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id) 
WHERE 
    ".JOB_TABLE."_display = '1' 
AND ".JOB_TABLE.".".CAT_TABLE."_id = ".CAT_TABLE.".".CAT_TABLE."_id
AND ".JOB_TABLE.".".LOC_TABLE."_id = ".LOC_TABLE.".".LOC_TABLE."_id
AND ".CAT_TABLE."_display = '1' 
AND ".LOC_TABLE."_display = '1' 
$conds_cat 
$conds_loc
GROUP BY ".JOB_TABLE.".".JOB_TABLE."_id 
ORDER BY ".JOB_TABLE."_rank DESC";
```

Update: fixed two mistakes that would cause PHP errors or incorrect SQL results.
Update 2: fixed a bug in the category/location filters

Comment: dwurf, thanks for the code, I have replaced it however nothing changes in the loading time? I appreciate your help, I am not really helpful as I do html but don't know a lot about php and sql so thank you. I have updated the code that follows in my original post

Comment: My original version has no semantic changes, it only makes the query more readable. See my update. Also, you must be **very** careful about pasting random code from the internet onto your production website when you don't understand it. At the very least I could make a mistake (after all I have no way of testing this) and your site goes down. At the worst I could be dropping tables or poking around at your private data.

Comment: Also, please please please keep a backup of the original file. Not doing so would be lunacy.

Comment: Thanks dwurf, I appreciate your help and your warning, off course I keep a backup file :), this is error I get: 
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/guided/public_html/scripts/database/class_db_mysql.php on line 399

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/guided/public_html/scripts/database/class_db_mysql.php on line 399

on the other hand the page loads super fast, but it doesn't load any of the vacancies and it gives the application option straight away.

Comment: @user1983090 I found another mistake, please try again. I'm attempting to test this myself as well.

Comment: @user1983090 one more fix applied. I have simulated your database as best I can at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/122fe/5. This is as much as I'm willing to do for you, if it doesn't work this time you're going to have to do some leg work. Find out how to display errors, inspect the query for obvious mistakes, etc.

Comment: fair enough dwurf, thanks for all your help. The warning error is still showing up so I will continue to work based on your code.

Answer (score 1):

I would first make sure its not injectable. yout taking input directly from the user and sending directly to the database. The only checks are that there is something there.

PHP / MySQL have the tools for validating this. Im not sure what function you use to query the database but i will assume its the standard mysql library ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

But also note the red warning on the top, Its out dated (though still works)

Comment: It's not clear whether the input has sanitised or not. The input has been processed in some way (otherwise it would be in `$_REQUEST` still). Lets hope for the OP's sake that sanitisation has been done.